# Models Observable to log eloquent action to table

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I want to "log" all the actions that eloquent models do in a table in database.

The idea is to keep a table like this:

```
|   Model    |  TimeStamp  | SQL Query as String | Transaction ID |
|:-----------|------------:|:-------------------:|:--------------:|
| User1      |  TimeStamp  |     magic query     |       id_1
| User2      |  TimeStamp  |     magic query     |       id_2
| Task1      |  TimeStamp  |     magic query     |       id_3
| Task2      |  TimeStamp  |     magic query     |       id_3
```

I am been reading about Laravel Observable but I have only found documentation for one model and I want a general one for all models.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: RDBMS's have logging, but it's vendor-specific. Which are you using?

Comment: It is not about a log in a file but in a table, to later study it